# DRF ModelViewSet is possible to create custom @action with same url and different methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have custom function with @action decorator for routing with two methods GET and DELETE.

Everything works ok if code is in same function and I can run different operations with simple if:

```
    @action(methods=['GET', 'DELETE'], detail=False, url_path='current', url_name='profile-current',
            permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def get_current_profile(self, request: Request, **kwargs) -> Response:
        if self.request.method == 'DELETE':
        ...
```

However I would like to separate the code into two functions still with same route, but different method.

If I separate code into two functions and same url-path and different methods, one of the methods returns method not available error.

Am I missing something here or is not possible to create methods in the way I thought it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to split the two methods like this

**GET method**

```
    @action(
        methods=['GET'],
        detail=False,
        url_path='current',
        url_name='profile-current',
        permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    )
    def get_current_profile(self, request: Request, **kwargs):
        """Get current profile"""
```

**DELETE method**

```
    @get_current_profile.mapping.delete
    def delete_current_profile(self, request, **kwargs):
        """Delete current profile"""
```

Link here:[Doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions)

Comment: You deserve to be chosen. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to separate the two methods within the function like this:

```python
    @action(
        methods=['GET', 'DELETE'],
        detail=False,
        url_path='current',
        url_name='profile-current',
        permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    )
    def get_current_profile(self, request: Request, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "GET":
            """Get current profile"""
        elif request.method == "DELETE":
            """Delete current profile"""
```